# How to use Rhythmbox python console

Tags: rhythmbox, python

Maybe this is obvious and I am missing it, or maybe someone's already written a great guide and my (seeming exhaustive) googling is failing to turn it up, but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get the darn python console in rhythmbox to **do** anything!

I've enabled it from the plugin menu, and then open it using Tools->Python Console.

It prints

```
You can access the main window through the 'shell' variable :
<rb.Shell object at 0xa6cdd24 (RBShell at 0xa14e000)>
>>>
```

But anything I type at the prompt does **nothing**!
I've tried `help`, I've tried `exit()`, I've tried `print "hello world"`, nothing does anything!

All of these things work, of course, in a normal python console. I haven't a clue what the devil the difference is here! Am I supposed to do something other than hit enter?

Comment: I just knew "rhythmbox-client -h" from terminal. +1 for making aware of this plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holy crap, I just found out what the problem was (2.5 years later)—for some reason my "enter" key maps to two different key events depending on whether numlock is on or off. When numlock is on, it returns `KP_ENTER`, and when numlock is off, it returns `Return`. I always have numlock on, because I prefer entering numbers with the keypad.

Unfortunately, the python console in Rhythmbox only recognizes `Return` to run a command—the `KP_ENTER` event just enters a line break...

But easy fix, just turn off numlock when using the console. I've ran into this problem in a few other applications (usually games), so I'm going to look into a better long-term solution (maybe forcing both to map to `Return` somehow)...

Comment: In case someone else has this problem, I did find a long-term solution:

`xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap`

to create a custom layout, then at the end of that file add a line 

`keysym KP_Enter = Return`

then run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to enable the new custom layout for this session. 

To make it autorun for the future, add the following to `~/.xinitrc`:
`if [ -f $HOME/.Xmodmap ]; then
    /usr/bin/xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap
fi`

Comment: curse comments and their lack of line breaks! the `if` statement added to `.xinitrc` needs to have line breaks after `then` and before `fi`.

Comment: Why don't you use the `return` key instead of the numlock's `enter` key?

Comment: I was using the main "Enter" key, not the one in the numpad; for some reason having numlock on/off made a difference for that one too.

Comment: CentOS 6.7 but with anaconda python, the Enter key on the NumberPad had a slightly different effect than the Enter key on the main keyboard.  NumLock did not have an effect.  The main keyboard Enter would return the '>>>' prompt, but the NumberPad Enter would return an empty line.

Answer (score 9):

The [Rhythmbox Plugins Writing Guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/Plugins/WritingGuide) has several examples of commands you can use in the Python console to control playback and modify Rhythmbox:

- Play/Pause

  ```
  shell.props.shell_player.playpause()
  ```
- Stop

  ```
  shell.props.shell_player.stop()
  ```
- Next track

  ```
  shell.props.shell_player.do_next()
  ```
- Add a song to the Play Queue

  ```
  shell.add_to_queue("file://awsome_song.ogg")
  ```
- Display a visualization

  ```
  import gst
  goom = gst.element_factory_make ("goom")
  sink = gst.element_factory_make ("ximagesink")
  colour = gst.element_factory_make ("ffmpegcolorspace")
  b = gst.Bin()
  b.add (goom, colour, sink)
  b.add_pad(gst.GhostPad("sink", goom.get_pad("sink")))
  goom.link(colour)
  colour.link(sink)
  shell.get_player().props.player.add_tee(b)
  ```

Comment: This is helpful, and actually I had found this previously, however what I am looking for is how to actually use the console. Is it just like a regular python console; type a command and hit enter? If so, then mine is broken. When I type a command and hit enter, it just makes a newline, without executing the line of code. As long as I know it's broken, then I can seek out help to fix it; I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something dumb (and couldn't find any documented use of it!)

Comment: That does indeed sound like something is broken. In rhythmbox-0.12.8-0ubuntu7 with no other plugins enabled, the console works just like a regular Python console, e.g. type in `print "hello world"` and then press Enter. I don't see this problem reported anywhere else yet, so you might consider opening a new bug in the [Rhythmbox bug tracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=rhythmbox).

Comment: thank you! now that i know it is broken, i'll poke around a bit more and file a bug report.

Comment: Note that at least as of Ubuntu Trusty tahr 14.04, rhythmbox embeds python 3.4.0.  So the command 'print "hello world"' is a syntax error ;)   Instead, use the new Python 3 print function:  'print("hello world")'

Comment: Note that some of these examples no longer work in Trusty.  See some hints on what to do instead of shell.add_to_queue() here - though it looks much more complicated, unfortunately: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/rhythmbox-devel/2011-April/msg00010.html

Answer (score 7):

As with any Python object, you can find out a lot about it by using the dir() method on it. This will give you a good place to start.

```
You can access the main window through the 'shell' variable :
<rb.Shell object at 0x9e9675c (RBShell at 0x987b018)>
>>> dir(rb.Shell)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__',
'__doc__', '__format__', '__gdoc__', '__getattribute__', '__gobject_init__', 
'__grefcount__', '__gtype__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', 
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
'__subclasshook__', 'add_to_queue', 'add_uri', 'add_widget', 'append_source',
'chain', 'connect', 'connect_after', 'connect_object', 'connect_object_after',
'disconnect', 'disconnect_by_func', 'do_notify', 'emit', 'emit_stop_by_name',
'freeze_notify', 'get_data', 'get_party_mode', 'get_player',
'get_playlist_manager', 'get_properties', 'get_property',
'get_source_by_entry_type', 'get_ui_manager', 'guess_source_for_uri', 
'handler_block', 'handler_block_by_func', 'handler_disconnect',
'handler_is_connected','handler_unblock', 'handler_unblock_by_func', 'load_uri',
'notebook_set_page', 'notify', 'notify_custom', 'present', 'props',
'register_entry_type_for_source', 'remove_from_queue', 'remove_widget',
'set_data', 'set_properties', 'set_property', 'stop_emission', 'thaw_notify',
'toggle_visibility', 'weak_ref']
```

You can then dir() any of the interesting-looking properties, like 'get_player', perhaps.

Another good place to look is if you see a __doc__ attribute on the object.

```
>>> print rb.Shell.__doc__
Object RBShell

Signals from RBShell:
  visibility-changed (gboolean)
  visibility-changing (gboolean, gboolean) -> gboolean
  create-song-info (RBSongInfo, gboolean)
  removable-media-scan-finished ()
  notify-playing-entry (gboolean)
  notify-custom (guint, gchararray, gchararray, GdkPixbuf, gboolean)

Properties from RBShell:
  no-registration -> gboolean: no-registration
    Whether or not to register
  no-update -> gboolean: no-update
    Whether or not to update the library
  dry-run -> gboolean: dry-run
    Whether or not this is a dry run
  rhythmdb-file -> gchararray: rhythmdb-file
    The RhythmDB file to use
  playlists-file -> gchararray: playlists-file
    The playlists file to use
  selected-source -> RBSource: selected-source
    Source which is currently selected
  db -> RhythmDB: RhythmDB
    RhythmDB object
  ui-manager -> GtkUIManager: GtkUIManager
    GtkUIManager object
  clipboard -> RBShellClipboard: RBShellClipboard
    RBShellClipboard object
  playlist-manager -> RBPlaylistManager: RBPlaylistManager
    RBPlaylistManager object
  removable-media-manager -> RBRemovableMediaManager: RBRemovableMediaManager
    RBRemovableMediaManager object
  shell-player -> RBShellPlayer: RBShellPlayer
    RBShellPlayer object
  window -> GtkWindow: GtkWindow
    GtkWindow object
  prefs -> RBShellPreferences: RBShellPreferences
    RBShellPreferences object
  queue-source -> RBPlayQueueSource: queue-source
    Queue source
  library-source -> RBLibrarySource: library-source
    Library source
  sourcelist-model -> RBSourceListModel: sourcelist-model
    RBSourcelistModel
  sourcelist -> RBSourceList: sourcelist
    RBSourcelist
  source-header -> RBSourceHeader: source header widget
    RBSourceHeader
  visibility -> gboolean: visibility
    Current window visibility

Signals from GObject:
  notify (GParam)
```

Comment: that's handy, if i can get the gorram console to work at all! as it is, if i type, for example, `dir(rb.Shell)` and hit enter, it just adds a line break and does nothing... Did your shell work OOB? I have the default rhythmbox installation on Ubuntu 10.04.... I can't think of anything that I've changed that would break the shell. My regular python console (outside of rb) works just fine...

Comment: Hm, yeah, my shell works fine with no modifications.